# Quarter-circular tube

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I don't like asking such elementary questions, but here I go.

This sketch is from the well-known book, **Hibbeler - Engineering Mechanics, Dynamics** (from their solutions manual, actually). The question is not about physics, though.
[image: Quarter-Circular-Tube]

The sketch depicts a quarter-circular tube **of radius $r$**. I was solving for $h_1$ on my own, where $h_1$ (see the image) is the vertical distance of the point $G$ (which is at $\theta=45\deg$ from the top of the tube): $$h_1=r-r\sin\dfrac\pi 4$$.

However, [R.C. Hibbeler](http://www.quepublishing.com/authors/bio/536216ea-8e2c-46c6-bf12-808ec8e7af7a) disagrees with me. Instead, he claims that: $$h_1=r-\dfrac{2r}{\pi}$$

In other scenario I would have no option other than think my solution is wrong (I am nowhere near his superior math/physics knowledge). However... this seems such a simple problem that leaves me wondering if he simply made a mistake.

I don't think the complete problem description will be of any use, but just in case, here it is:

[image: Problem-Description]

Any one help me spot my mistake? I'm going crazy. Thanks.

Comment: The book is correct. Try finding centre of gravity of the chain.

Comment: Your calculation has $G$ touching the tube wall, but it does not.

Comment: The center of gravity (G) is at $\theta=\pi/4$ isn't it? And from there, I simply calculate the vertical distance of G using the sine of this angle and the radius of the tube.

Comment: @WeatherVane But the thickness is supposed to be negligible right? And therefore G can be considered touching the wall.

Comment: See what weather vane said. Its not touching the wall, its further closer to the centre.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it another try. Thank you guys for the hint, I'll get back to you in case I can't get it done.

Comment: $G$ is not even touching the chain.

Comment: @JoseLopezGarcia One tip: Try integration for finding centroid. You will get the distance of centroid from centre $O$ as $\tfrac{r \sin(\theta / 2)}{ \theta / 2}$ where $\theta$ is the angle subtended by arc on centre (Here $\theta = 90 ^ \circ$)

Comment: Cool, useful hint. You may want to leave an answer to the question or something. My error was considering G is touching the wall.

Comment: Solved it! $G=(2r/\pi, 2r/\pi)$. I learnt a lesson so I'm glad I asked this question. Should I delete it since it has no answers? Or should I leave it here?

Comment: Perhaps post an answer to your own question. Note that the CG of the chain is never *on the chain* until it is straight - in this example, although it might be with a S shape chain, etc.